# render multiplication and division signs in textarea using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a very simple math editor, and I want users to be able to input [÷] and [×] by clicking on buttons.  I have put these characters directly in the code.  They are rendering as errors.  When I try to use **&divide;** or **&times;** the textarea shows *&divide;* or *&times;* rather than [÷] or [×].  I have CSS to set the font to Arial.

The code receives a param called `newSymbol` and then appends it:

```
var textArea = $('#symbolsTextArea');
textArea.val(textArea.val() + newSymbol);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oxuxun/2/edit works just fine.

Comment: Make sure your source files are saved as UTF-8.

Comment: `textArea.val(textArea.val() + $("<div></div>").html(newsymbol).text());` - http://jsfiddle.net/RbHuS/ (when you set the content with `.val()` it doesn't do anything with html markup, it just sets the string as is, so convert the html as shown or just use the actual character rather than an html character entity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the unicode characters instead of an HTML special character.

```
textArea.val(function(i, val) {
    return val + "\u00f7";
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/QcjCZ/

---

Or if the HTML sequences are easier for you to remember, create a map of HTML to unicode:

```
var symbol = {
    "&divide;":"\u00f7",
    "&times;": "\u00d7"
};
```

And use it like this:

```
textArea.val(function(i, val) {
    return val + symbol["&divide;"];
});
```

Comment: `\u00d7` will get you the times symbol.